# How to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace in Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-blade-cli

I am trying to migrate a theme from the plugins sdk to workspace.

The steps I actually did:

1- I installed ***BLADE CLI*** on my windows 7 operating system. I followed this link: [INSTALLING BLADE CLI](https://dev.liferay.com/fr/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-blade-cli).

2- Then in the ***gradle.properties*** file under the ***liferay-workspace***, I uncomment this line:

> liferay.workspace.plugins.sdk.dir=plugins-sdk

and I created a directory *plugins-sdk* under the *liferay-workspace* and I put my project theme in it.

3- I checked the ***BLADE CLII*** if it works:

> C:\Users\User1\liferay-workspace>blade version
>
> C:\Users\User1\liferay-workspace>2.2.0.201707061805

4- Then, I tried to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace using this command `blade convert --themebuilder nameThemeProject`.

I typed the command and nothing happens.

The structure of the theme project:

[theme structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbSZ3.jpg)

I followed this link:
[plugins-sdk-to-workspace](https://dev.liferay.com/fr/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/migrating-a-theme-from-the-plugins-sdk-to-workspace).

**Before trying to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace:**

I tried to create a new gradle Theme project and then paste the contents of the *old theme project* into the *new theme project*.

This is what I did:

1- I created a new project *File -> new -> Liferay Module Project*.

2- On Right side there is pannel which blink green colour. right click on *'build' ->'run Gradle Tasks'*

3- Then refresh the theme project.

4- I checked the "build folder" in *the system explorer* under the theme project.

5- I copied folders and files which you need to change into *src/main/webapp/*   I copied the contents of *"_diffs"* of the old theme project in *"src/main/webapp"*

6- Build the project. right click on *'build' ->'run Gradle Tasks'*

- I tried "buildTheme" no errors.
- I tried "build" there is some errors.
  But nothing works.

[server error in the theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBB8N.jpg)

The issue on the theme:

[issue theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIxz6.png)

sorry, my theme works on Liferay 7.0 GA3 and later. I have this in my liferay-look-and-feel.xml file before migrating the theme: `<compatibility><version>7.0.2+</version></compatibility>`. I tested it on liferay 7 GA1 and I got a issue.

#### Update:

I did not find a solution to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace. I want a structure project like a new Theme project on Eclipse IDE with build type Gradle.

[theme structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M57Bu.jpg)

Comment: can you give some more hints than "nothing happens"? And rather list the steps you actually did than pointing to the tutorial? (how did you point your workspace to the plugins-sdk? Which other steps did you do before?)

Comment: @OlafKock Sorry, I added more details. Pls check the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Although technically the theme update is possible, if you care about the end result I would start from scratch and just copy the bits and pieces that make sense. It should be easy if you did just few modification. If you have a lot of Liferay/Bootstrap overrides this will be more challenging but the auto update will not produce something nice.

Also, when people refer to Liferay theme they speak usually about CSS/ftl/js. If your theme contains something more (like JSP hooks...) these should be taken out and placed in separate bundles accordingly.

Comment: **Before trying to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace:**

I tried to create a new gradle Theme project and then paste the contents of the old theme project into the new theme project. But it did not work. I updated  the question pls check it again.

Comment: The theme that I am trying to update does not contains JSP, there is a folder hooks and I do not know what exactly is.

Comment: when I say start from scratch and copy over the staff that you need you can't just create an empty theme and copy over everything that you need. You can copy bit's and peases but not all. For example, you have an SCSS file that stiles some custom portlet. That can be copied. If you have there an SCSS file that modifies, for example, breadcrumbs portlet you need to copy it validate that it works and continue. Basically, it's a step by step process. First, sort out the ftl stuff then the CSS and last the JS. Step by step.

Comment: I copied the contents of "_diffs" of the old theme project in "src/main/webapp" of the new project. is what I did wrong. I can put the css folder structure and other folders. what exactly do I have to do? pls help me.

Comment: there is no webapp folder in liferay 7 themes. generate a project with https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/themes-generator#running-the-themes-generator and look at the structure. The old _diff stuff goes now into src

Comment: hello, I managed to import the project without making copy and paste but i have issue on the theme. this is that I get in my home page: 
An unexpected system error occurred. 

**javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.template.TemplateException: Unable to process template myNewTheme-theme_SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/portal_normal.ftl**

Comment: you have an error in the FTLs. Probably some variable is not initialized. Try to provide default fallbacks to overcome it and determine what variable causing problems

Comment: I have this error: **FreeMarker template error:
Java method "Object.equals(Object)" takes 1 argument, but 2 was given... in template "myNewTheme-theme_SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/init.ftl" at line 158, column 1]**. I found this error on this forum https://web.liferay.com/en/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/86514052  but I could not solve it.

Comment: Are you overriding the init.ftl? If you haven't then you might experience the mentioned problem. If you generated the project with the latest generator then you need to use also the latest liferay. Otherwise, you need to fix the code or use an older version of the liferay plugin. You would need to find the right version by try and error. I would suggest to go with the latest version path.

Comment: sorry, my theme works on Liferay 7.0 GA3 and later. I have this in my liferay-look-and-feel.xml file before migrating the theme:  `<compatibility><version>7.0.2+</version></compatibility>` I tested it on liferay 7 GA1 and I got a issue.

Comment: in that case, it's the problem described in the post

Comment: this command: **blade convert --themebuilder nameThemeProject** did not work.  **What i did is migrate the theme from plugin sdk to the Liferay Theme Generator**. I do not know if that's the good solution. I have not found a solution to migrate the theme from the plugins sdk to workspace. _This question is not solved._ I want a structure project
like creating a new Theme project on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: As I said in the answer you are better off in creating a NEW theme. Reuse bit and peases from the old one but DO NOT copy stuff over without checking step by step that it does not cause problems. GA1 is really old and should not be used! But if you want to use that you would need old Liferay npm dependencies (look at your package.json) and adjust accordingly.